# Jquery URL validation without http:// or https:// within rules

Tags: jquery, url, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validation.

```
rules: {  
    cityid: {  
        required: true
    },
    url: {  
        url: true
    }
}
```

Problem: When I enter facebook.com, it gives error of invalid url.
But I want url validation without http and https.

Comment: Then you'll have to make a copy of the existing URL rule and create a custom rule using the `.addMethod()` method.  See:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/

Answer (score 1):

this is working for me !!

```
function isValidUrl(url){

 var myVariable = url;
    if(/(^|\s)((https?:\/\/)?[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+\.?(:\d+)?(\/\S*)?)/.test(myVariable)) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return -1;
    }   
}
```

pass your url value using url object from your input or form

above regex is make http or https part optional for url, it accept both Without http or https and with http or https urls.

Maybe it's solve your problem :)

Comment: This does not answer the question.  The OP is using the jQuery Validate plugin.